# Deployment of DAPP smart Contract on Ethereum MainNet

Tags: web3js, truffle, contract-deployment, infura

We are developing a DAPP based on ethereum. Current we are developing based on testrpc and its working perfectly. 
We do want to decide on where to deploy DAPP. 
Can we deploy on public Ethereum blockchain. 
Is there any other variables that need to be considered when deployed a smart contract of the  decentralised application other than token in ethereum network ?

What about decentralised private ethereum blockchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really just depends upon your application; you should consider the speed and cost of the mainnet and make sure that doesn't hurt your application too much.

Other than that, there isn't much else to consider.

You asked about using a decentralized private Ethereum blockchain. Generally private blockchains are faster but much more centralized than the mainnet, so it really just depends on your type of application and how decentralized you want to be.

*You  might also want to check out Loom Network @ https://loomx.io/